# PHP Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error

Tags: php

I have an array of objects with multiple keys in php:

```
Array
(
[0] =&gt; stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] =&gt; 4983
        [post_id] =&gt; 56357
        [date] =&gt; 2016-06-04 23:45:28          
    )

[1] =&gt; stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] =&gt; 4982
        [post_id] =&gt; 56241
        [date] =&gt; 2016-06-04 22:58:27           
    )
 )
```

Then I am using the following to change the date format:

```
foreach($results as &$row) {    
   $row['date'] = ago($row['date']);
}
```

However I keep getting `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` error.

Any suggestions to why it is occurring?

Comment: You need to fetch data with `mysql_fetch_*` functions. Your `$result` variable is a `resource` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: you should NOT be getting that result at all. you're json_encoding a mysql result handle, which is **NOT** the results themselves.

Comment: I removed the top section of the question. It was a simplified version. Let just say that I am getting the results and I need to replace the `date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access it as an object. Its an array of objects... Your `var_dump` showed that. Here is how your for loop should look...

```
foreach($results as &$row) {    
   $row->date = ago($row->date);
}
```

Using the `->` is how you access object properties.